# Check for specific value in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check that a combobox in winforms contains some value?

Is there any way of doing it without iterating through all items?

Comment: As in any value?  A selected value?  Any items in the combobox?

Comment: @Brettski: items in the combobox

Comment: Combobox item collection information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Contains("some value"))
{

}
```

If the items are some custom object instead of strings you might need to override the [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method.

Answer (score 10):

`int index = comboBox1.FindString("some value");
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx#Y500

There's also FindStringExact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb.aspx

Comment: I find this much more flexible

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me.

This did:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(i => i == position))
{
    // Items contains value
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

To find exact data from combo box we have to check with FindStringExact

int resultIndex = cbEmployee1.FindStringExact(item.Text);

Answer (score 2):

Using the accepted answer did not work for me as it always returned false even though a check of the list show the value present. What I use is the FindStringExact method, as recommend by Louis and Amit. In this case its a value entered in the comboBox text box.

```
var index = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text)
if(index > -1)
{
    //Success followup code
}
```